# How do I use a wildcard when using VBA in Excel to do Workbook.open for a directory name?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I am using workbooks.open to get to an excel file in a directory that name will change based on revisions. I will be coping some cells form this excel workbook into my active workbook.

The current file I need to go to is in the following directory:

```
d:\masters\777\software\7770123 Rev A\7770123.xlsx
```

The 7770123 Rev A folder will occasionally change when revisions are made to the xlsx file.

When 7770123 Rev A changes to 7770123 Rev B the 7770123 Rev A folder will be replace with a 7770123 Rev B folder.

The 7770123 Rev A folder will be removed in the directory.
The xlsx file is the only file in the 7770123 Rev ? folder.

Here is what I have working for a fixed directory structure. Need to know how/if I can do it with wildcard?

```
Dim wbkFrom, wbkTo As Workbook

Set wbkTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbkFrom = Workbooks.Open("d:\masters\777\software\7770123 Rev A\7770123.xlsx")

wbkFrom.Sheets("Jigs").Range("A1:H500").Copy

wbkTo.Sheets("Jigs").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

only change folderpath as follows:
Set wbkFrom = Workbooks.Open("d:\masters\777\software\7770123 Rev " & Sheets("").Range ("A1").value &"\7770123.xlsx")
where Sheets("").Range("A1").value may be "A" or "B" or use any other cell in a sheet for this input

Comment: Would this cell containing the "A" or "B" be in a sheet in the 77701223.xlsx or my active workbook?

Answer (score 0):

@Randy Withcomb: your active workbook

Comment: This would result in having to update the active worksheet with the updated revision letter of the wkbFrom file. If I was going to do that then I would just update the VBA code as I have it to the new letter. Either of these methods would involve making a change to the active workbook prior to running the code. I am looking for a way to have the VBA code figure this out when it runs. Hope this makes sense.